# linux system file writes to flash card, efficiency and flash endurance

Tags: linux, filesystem, file

I've got a more common question. I come from bare metal microcontroller development - there we usually avoid flash write access for several reasons. one is to avoid damage of the flash memory because of too many erase/write cycles.

the raspberry is running from a sd card, which is also flash memory.

So i ask myself whats with the linux system running on a embedded system and the "everything is a file" philosophy.

Is the system writing every time physically to the flash (e.g. for logging) or is there a driver layer which collects requests and writes bigger blocks delayed to the physical semiconductor?

When i write scripts for the embedded system, should I avoid redirection like `foo > tmp.file` temporary file writes when the script is running every minute and data could be also held in RAM?

i am curious whats your expert opinion about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the problem seems to underestimate the write life of the given flash memory.

> "everything is a file" philosophy.

This is true, but only kind of. The "everything is a file" philosophy doesn't mean it's a legitimate (as in physical) file. `/proc/cpuinfo`, for example, is a "file", but it doesn't reside anywhere on the disk. It's a virtual file. Anything you write to or read from that "file" is coming straight from memory.

> Is the system writing every time physically to the flash (e.g. for logging) or is there a driver layer which collects requests and writes bigger blocks delayed to the physical semiconductor?

All modern operating systems have a buffer that tries to make writing more efficient. So, in some sense, it will try to block the data a little, but the RPi will log just like any other desktop/server OS.

> When I write scripts for the embedded system, should I avoid redirection like foo > tmp.file temporary file writes when the script is running every minute and data could be also held in RAM?

It's not really necessary to avoid the temporary writes. I would just log directly to the file. I find your design choice a little odd, but it's not wrong or ill advised per say.

Comment: thank you.    what did you mean with "log directly to the file" , just to do not use **temporary** (files)

Comment: @user3336433: correct. I don't see a point in using a temporary file when you could just write to whatever the normal file is.

Comment: right.   but if i am on shell and may need a step in between (may for debugging) its difficult to have an alternative. let say to put a file into a temp. buffer located in RAM. `/tmp` is also located inside non volatile memory, or ?

Comment: @user3336433: If you have a legitimate need for a temporary file, then go for it as you're already doing. I thought you were trying to use a temp file to somehow reduce device writing.

Comment: And yes, `/tmp` is usually stored on the sdcard, but that may change slightly based on the distro.

Comment: is such a directory  holding files in RAM on debian distribution ?

Comment: @user3336433: Sort of. They're not files in the intuitive sense of the word. The basically an interface to the OS/kernel that can be read as if it was a file. This is a feature of linux in general, and should be true of any standard distribution.

Comment: Okay.. and where is it located ?

Comment: The example I gave was `/proc/cpuinfo`. As far as the filesystem is concerned that's where it's located. As far as reality goes, there's no real file sitting in memory or on the disk. It's an interface.